# RMarkdown using readthedown template to knit, only show colors

Tags: r, templates, rstudio, r-markdown

just installed the package, and tried to use the readthedown template, but when I knit it to html. file, everything runs smoothly but I got this page [as you can see in the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AngeK.png)

```
---
title: ""
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output:
  rmdformats::material:
    highlight: kate
---
```

Comment: I am unsure that you can evaluate r code inside quotes. Do you have something to cover that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that you have nothing to show ... so it appears all green. Your "header" `##babe I like your stlye` is inside the r code.
When I run your code in the following way, it all works well:

````
---
title: ""
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output:
  rmdformats::material:
    highlight: kate
---

# Summary

```{r}
summary(mtcars)
```
# Plot

```{r}
plot(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$hp)
```
````

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for your detailed answer !! LOL I'm totally new to this... also wondering every time I knit it, it'd create a html file on my desktop which I don't really need. Do you know how can I change the setting and avoid that?